# Selenium: Issue with reassignment in For Loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried debugging my program with print statements to see what was going on during each iteration.

This part works fine:
The program goes through a total of 50 combinations of the drop-down menus (25 for each year).

This part isn't working:
However, for some reason the totals dictionary is only storing the inputs from the second iteration of the initial "year" for-loop. It is returning a dictionary with a length of 25 (only half of what I actually want).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

# General Stuff about the website
path = '/Users/admin/desktop/projects/scraper/chromedriver'
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=path)
website = 'http://siops.datasus.gov.br/filtro_rel_ges_covid_municipal.php'
driver.get(website)

# Initial Test: printing the title
print(driver.title)
print()

# Dictionary to Store stuff in
totals = {}

### Drop Down Menus ###
state_select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cmbUF"]'))
state_options = state_select.options

year_select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cmbAno"]'))
year_options = year_select.options

# county_select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cmbMunicipio"]'))
# county_select.select_by_value('120025')

# report_select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="gesRelatorio"]'))
# report_select.select_by_value('rel_ges_covid_rep_uniao_municipal.php')

# period_select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cmbPeriodo"]'))
# period_select.select_by_value('14')

### Loop through all combinations ###
for year in range(1, 3):
    year_select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cmbAno"]'))
    year_select.select_by_index(year)

    for index in range(0, len(state_options) - 1):
        state_select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cmbUF"]'))
        state_select.select_by_index(index)

        # Click the Submit Button
        submit_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/input[2]')
        submit_button.click()

        # Pulling data from the webpage
        nameof = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="arearelatorio"]/div[1]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]').text
        total_balance = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="arearelatorio"]/div[1]/div/table[3]/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]').text
        paid_expenses = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="arearelatorio"]/div[1]/div/table[4]/tbody/tr[11]/td[4]').text

        # Update Dictionary with the new info
        totals.update({nameof: [total_balance, paid_expenses, year]})
        
        print([nameof, year])
        driver.back()

# Print the final Dictionary and quit
print(len(totals))
print(totals)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: the path should include the chrome driver file extension

Comment: @KelishaZ I don't think this is what's causing the issue. I am not getting any errors when I run the script. The problem is simply that "totals" is only being assigned to the second iteration of the year For-Loop, rather than storing the elements from both iterations.

Comment: Just a wild guess but is it possible that you overwrite the value for the same key in the dictionary. Since this is a dictionary and keys should be unique, this might be the reason to have only the second iteration values.

Comment: I got no errors in your code. it seems fine. maybe try increasing the range from 3 to 4. because the for loop iterates only two rounds in your code.

Comment: @AlexKaramfilov You were right! The keys were the same during each iteration, so it was just modifying the values rather than creating a new key-value pair. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome, please mark it as answer for the question.

Comment: @AlexKaramfilov I don't think I'm able to mark a comment as an answer to the question, so I created an answer and referenced you. Feel free to make an answer of your own, and I will delete mine and mark yours as correct.

Answer (score 2):

@Alex Karamfilov figured it out with his comment:

"Just a wild guess but is it possible that you overwrite the value for the same key in the dictionary. Since this is a dictionary and keys should be unique, this might be the reason to have only the second iteration values "

It was a dumb error on my part. The keys were the same during each iteration, so it was just modifying the values rather than creating a new key-value pair.